# php. why function's running time is big?

Tags: php, profiling

I am profiling my code in php. Question is about next function:

```
// returns true if edge exists in the tree
protected function edgeExist( $srcNodeId, $firstToken ) {
    $result = array_key_exists( $srcNodeId, $this->edges )
              && array_key_exists( $firstToken, $this->edges[$srcNodeId]);
    return $result;
}
```

According to the profiler, function `edgeExist` consumes about 10% of running time, but function `array_key_exists` consumes about 0.2% of running time.
Why does function `edgeExist` consume so much?

Comment: Try using `isset`, it *may* be faster than `array_key_exists`. eg `$result = isset($srcNodeId[$this->edges]) && isset($firstToken[$this->$this->edges[$srcNodeId]]);`.

Comment: but anyway `array_key_exists` is fast enough, it consumes 0.2% of running time. I cannot understand why `edgeExist` consumes so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be faster, try it:

```
protected function edgeExist( $srcNodeId, $firstToken ) {
    return isset($this->edges[$srcNodeId][$firstToken]);
}
```

There is a small difference when using `array_key_exists()` and `isset()`. Look in to the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try compare profile results for

```
protected function edgeExist( $srcNodeId, $firstToken ) {
    $result = array_key_exists( $firstToken, array());
    return $result;
}
```

and

```
protected function edgeExist( $srcNodeId, $firstToken ) {
    $result = array_key_exists( $firstToken, $this->edges[$srcNodeId]);
    return $result;
}
```

I guess maybe $this->edges[$srcNodeId] is some huge array and php needs to make some internal magic on it.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, because it would mess up logic of the program and it would not be run

Comment: I do not understand you problem with messing up logic, I hope you are not in production mode ;). Nevermind, if you do not want to change edgeExist then you can add 2 new methods edgeExist2, edgeExist3 then invoke them and omit returned result.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the time each part ran by:

```
protected function edgeExist( $srcNodeId, $firstToken ) {
    $time = microtime();
    $result1 = array_key_exists( $srcNodeId, $this->edges )
    $time2 = microtime();
    $result2 = array_key_exists( $firstToken, $this->edges[$srcNodeId]);
    $time3 = microtime();
    $result = $result1 && $result2;
    $time4 = microtime();
    echo "calculating the first result took " . $time2 - $time1 . " microseconds\n".
    echo "calculating the second result took " . $time3 - $time2 . " microseconds\n".
    echo "calculating the && took " . $time4 - $time3 . " microseconds\n".
    return $result;
}
```

This should solve the mystery ;)